# Alternating between reading forwards and backwards in a loop

Tags: math, logic

My array is 1D m in length. say m = 16

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

The way I actually interpret the array is n x n = m

0 1 2 3

4 5 6 7

8 9 10 11

12 13 14 15

I require to read the array in this manner due to the way my physical environment is set up

0 4 8 12 13 9 5 1 2 6 10 14 15 11 7 3

What I came up with works but I really don't think it is the best way to do this:

```
bool isFlipped = true;
int x = 0; x < m; x++
if(isFlipped)
     newLine[x] = line[((n-1)-x%n)*n + x/n)]
else
     newLine[x] = line[x%n*n +x/n]
if(x != 0 && x % n == 0)
     isFlipped = !isFlipped
```

This gives me the required result but I really think there is a way to get rid of this boolean by purely using a math formula. I am stuffing this into a 8kb microcontroller and I need to conserve as much space as  I can because I will have some bluetooth communication and more math going into it later on.

Edit:

Thanks to a user I got to a one line solution-ish. (the below would replace the lines in the for-loop)

```
c=x/n
newLine[x] = line[((c+1)%2)*((x%n)*n+c) + (c%2)*((n-1)-2*(x%n))*n ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to utilize the fact that odd columns in the n*n matrix are read from down up, and even columns are read from up down.

A number at index x in newLine is located in column number c=floor(x/n) in the n*n matrix. c%2 is 0 for even columns and 1 for odd columns. So something like this should work:

```
int c = x/n;
newLine[x] = line[(x%n)*n + (c%2)*((n-1)-2*(x%n))*n + c];
```

Comment: This is why i like the internet. I will use your approach today and see what I can come up with. Will report back. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So I have modified your solution a little bit. newLine[x] = line[((c+1)%2)*((x%n)*n+c) + (c%2)*((n-1)-2*(x%n))*n ]; this works for me. thanks a bunch!